# Prove the set $\{v \in V : f(v)=w_0\}$ is $ v_0+U$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Be $f:V\to W$ a linear transformation and $U$ kernel of $f$. Be $w_0 \in W$ for which exist an element $v_0 \in V$ such that $f(v_0)=w_0$. Prove that the set,

$$\{v \in V: f(v)=w_0\}$$

is $v_0 +U$.

I tried to take a general vector and work with it, but i dont got it nothing, any help is going to be usefull! thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose  $f (v)=w_0$. Then $f (v)=f (v_0) $ or $f (v-v_0)=0$. So $v-v_0\in\ker f $. Can you complete now?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{v\in V:f(v)=w_0\}$ and $B=v_0+U$. $B\subseteq A$ because for any $u\in U$
$$f(v_0+u)=f(v_0)+f(u)=w_0+0=w_0$$
$A\subseteq B$ because for any $v\in A$
$$f(v-v_0)=f(v)-f(v_0)=w_0-w_0=0$$
and thus $u=v-v_0\in U$, thus $v=u+v_0$ is of the desired form. Therefore $A=B$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the linearity of $f$ and the fact that $f(u)=0$ for any $u\in U$.

> The set $v_0+U$ is the set of vectors of the form $v=v_0+u$, $u\in U$. Since $f$ is linear, $f(v)=f(v_0+u)=f(v_0)+f(u)=f(v_0)=w_0$. For the inclusion in the other direction, observe that $v-v_0 \in U$ and $v=v_0+v-v_0\in v_0+U$.